# createStackNavigator with createBottomTabNavigator, header or tab didn't appear

Tags: react-native-navigation

I've an issue to display both, the header and the bottom tab navigation at the same time.

Here is my TabNavigator ->

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Main: Screens.MainContainer,
        Main2: Screens.MainContainer,
        Main3: Screens.MainContainer,
        Main4: Screens.MainContainer,
    },
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        showIcon: false,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: 'blue',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }
)

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Opening: Screens.OpeningContainer,
        SignupSide: Screens.SignupSideContainer,
        SignupSkills: Screens.SignupSkillsContainer,
        SignupCredentials: Screens.SignupCredentialsContainer,
        SignupValidation: Screens.SignupValidationContainer,
        Signin: Screens.SigninContainer,
        Main: Screens.MainContainer,
        ServerDown: Screens.ServerDownContainer,
        TabNavigator,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Opening',
    }
)

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator)
```

All my screen except MainContainer have header desactivated with this navigationOptions ->

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ header: null })
```

My screen OpeningContainer (initialRoute), just redirect the user to the MainContainer after doing some API call

My MainContainer got this header ->

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: <HeaderSearchBar />,
  })
```

- When I open the app, with the current state, the bottom tab bar didn't appear.
- If I change initialRoute to 'TabNavigator' It lead the app to the main screen (first one on the TabNavigator list), and it display the tab bottom bar, however, the header is display but the SearchBar inside is missing (it is an empty header)..

I have try many different way to implement it and I can't figure how to properly get both, header and bottom tab bar working.

Someone got an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The below code may useful

   ```
   const navOptionHandler = (navigation)=> ({
         header: null 
         }); 

   const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
         {
          Opening: {Screens.OpeningContainer,
             navigationOptions: navOptionHandler},
           SignupSide: Screens.SignupSideContainer,
           SignupSkills: Screens.SignupSkillsContainer,
           SignupCredentials: Screens.SignupCredentialsContainer,
           SignupValidation: Screens.SignupValidationContainer,
           Signin: Screens.SigninContainer,
           Main: Screens.MainContainer,
           ServerDown: Screens.ServerDownContainer,
           TabNavigator,
           },
           {
           initialRouteName: 'Opening',
           }
           )
   ```